# Vue.js: Set a condition for radio type (radio-button)

Tags: vue.js, radio-button

How can i set a condition for radio in Vue.js?
I want to make radio buttons depend on a specific object i choose from above codes. "select" does work well and it's so easy for set a value depend on an object that i choose using :value="object.variable". like below

Select example (It works by condition = a object that i choose):

```
<span class="select">
<select :value="object.variable">
 <option>true</option>
 <option>false</option>
</select>
</span>
```

(If "object.variable" is true, then the select box displays true.)

My original code:

```
<div class="control">
 <label class="label">true_or_false</label>
 <input type="radio" name="picked" id="true" value="true" v-model="picked">
 <label for="true">True</label>
 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="picked" id="false" value="false" v-model="picked">
 <label for="false">False</label>
 <br>
 <span>Picked: {{ picked }}</span>
</div>
```

I want to make the above to a below like this.

```
<div class="control" :value="object.variable">
 <label class="label">One or Two</label>
 <input type="radio" name="picked" id="true" value="true" v-model="picked">
 <label for="true">True</label>
 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="picked" id="false" value="false" v-model="picked">
 <label for="false">False</label>
 <br>
 <span>Picked: {{ picked }}</span>
</div>
```

I googled all day, but i didn't find any information about this.
I don't want to use v-on, event handling, for this lightweight requirement. and v-if doesn't work.
I can't understand why "radio" doesn't handle these :/ unlike "select".

Comment: I am not sure what is the problem here. The second snippet should work fine. Could you expand on what you need?

Comment: @Nisarg Shah "object.variable" has "true" value. But when i execute last codes (that has <div class="control" :value="object.variable">) radio-button doesn't do anything. I expected that "true" radio-button is On, when i get "object.variable". I want to make passive radio-button that auto-selected by object's variable (condition).

Comment: Did you try replacing `v-model="picked"` with `v-model="object.variable"`?

Comment: How weird ... I did that solution many times saying wtf why it doesn't work?
 lol. It's works fine. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Don't update the question with the solution. It is not considered a good practice here. I've posted the solution as an answer below for future visitors. You can accept my answer to indicate that it solves the problem.

Comment: Sorry for that. It's first time i upload a question. and thanks for announcing a good practice. so kind of you :) have a nice day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the `object.variable` as the binding expression for `v-model`. Like this:

```
<div class="control">
 <label class="label">true_or_false</label>
 <input type="radio" name="picked" id="true" value="true" v-model="object.variable">
 <label for="true">True</label>
 <br>
 <input type="radio" name="picked" id="false" value="false" v-model="object.variable">
 <label for="false">False</label>
 <br>
 <span>Picked: {{ picked }}</span>
</div>
```